# How to add Aggregate in 'IF' expression in Tableau

Tags: if-statement, average, tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I had a dummy dataset, it contains transaction data.

So basically i want to create a parameter of month (already) from jan-dec.
Then create a calculated field each current month and previous month each metrics for sales, transaction and AOV.

Example for sales: [CM Sales]

```
IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN [sales] END
```

for transaction: [CM Orders]

```
COUNT(IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN [PO numbers] END)
```

But in Average Order Value (AOV): [CM AOV]

```
IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN [CM Sales] / [CM Orders] END
```

but it said error cannt mix aggregate

Also i tried manually create a calculated field AOV:

```
SUM([Sales])/COUNT([PO numbers])
```

it worked but if i add to this calculated field [CM AOV]:

```
IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN [AOV] END
```

Still error

Then i tried to use fixed function

```
IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN { FIXED [Month]: [AOV]} END
```

it worked but the calculations was incorrect
Also try

```
IF [Month] =  Month([transaction_date]) THEN { FIXED Month([transaction_date]): [AOV]} END
```

it worked too but the calculations still incorrect

Please help the correct calculated field,
I want to have current month AOV, previous month AOV and percentages of change AOV (current AOV - previous AOV)/(previous AOV)

Thank you!